# Adding checkbox value into listview

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

im doing my final year project (Ordering System)

i want to add the checkbox values into the listview 
and i having problem with since no error display..

i do really need help here
please help me

[try to put the checkbox value into listview``](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kex4K.jpg)

```
Private Sub btnAddOrder_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddOrder.Click

    If cbSpagethi.Checked Then
        Dim item As New ListViewItem(cbSpagethi.Text)
        item.SubItems.Add(tbQSpagehti.Text)
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You instantiated the ListViewItem and gave it data, but never added that ListViewItem to the ListView.  Replace ListView1 with the name of your List View instance and you will see it:

```
    Dim item As New ListViewItem(cbSpagethi.Text)
    item.SubItems.Add(tbQSpagehti.Text)
    ListView1.Items.Add(item)
```

Comment: ooowwhh....it means i didnt tell where the values should go
thank you for helping me :)